# Cannot Build HoloColorPicker

Tags: java, android

I'm having a lot of trouble building `HoloColorPicker` into an app. I'm using Android IDE 1.5. The Java code is using `R.styleable....` to reference constants, and I can't find these constants anywhere in the downloaded code. I have limited experience with Java and Android, so it could be me. What am I missing?

Comment: Show us some code or the error that Android Studio tells you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave up on this one and went for a color picker called AmbilWarna. It's working well. Thanks again for the response - i'll leave better details next time.